# How to use testssl.sh on an SMTP server?

Tags: tls, openssl, smtp

I need your help with testing SMTP with testssl.sh.
This is the command that I run:

```
./testssl.sh -t smtp [IP]
```

Where the IP is the SMTP server IP where I know there is an SSL/TLS certificate.

With the preview command I receive an error message - "testssl.sh can't connect to SMPT server". I think it is an syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: -bash: ./testssl.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: the documentation shows you exactly what to do (specify the port)

Comment: i think your question is very good :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wget https://testssl.sh/testssl.sh`

`chmod +x testssl.sh`

`./testssl.sh --mx <domain name>`

works fine.

`./testssl.sh -t smtp <ip>:25`

and

`./testssl.sh -t smtp <ip>:587`

also work fine.

Note that not specifying the port assumes port 443, despite specifying protocol smtp. That doesn't work.

Comment: Also, you might try https://discovery.cryptosense.com/ which does the same thing only better.